# Asyncio does not run all tasks concurrently in Python. trying to export csv files in batches

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to read a big file and export batches of CSV files using Asyncio.
I know Asyncio does not support async IO for the same file, so I am trying to export to individual files per task giving the batch number. But it only runs synchronously..

I have main.py and it has a function `def start()`

```
def start():
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(processing.test_async(dictRunData))
```

I have processing.py and has a function `test_async()`

```
async def test_async(dictRunData):
  num_logical_cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
  with open(dictRunData['input_file'], 'r') as infile:
    content = infile.read().replace('\n', '')
    lstcontent = ast.literal_eval(content)

  tasks = []
  chunkNum = 0
  chunk_contents = numpy.array_split(numpy.array(lstcontent), num_logical_cpus)
  print(f"number of chunks: {len(chunk_contents)}")
  for chunk in chunk_contents:
    chunkNum += 1
    task = asyncio.create_task(process_chunk_async(chunk, chunkNum))
    tasks.append(task)

  result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
```

Here is the function process the given chunk.

```
async def process_chunk_async(chunk, chunkNum, dictRunData):
    dict_results = {}
    for data in chunk:
       ..do something..
       dict_results.append(data)

    outputfile = await write_chunk_async(dict_results, chunkNum, dictRunData)
```

Here is the `write_chunk_async`

```
async def write_chunk_async(dict_results, chunkNum, dictRunData):
    fileName = f"_{chunkNum}.csv"
    wrtieFileTo = open(fileName,"a+")

    for data in dict_results.keys():
        wrtieFileTo.write(data + "\n")

    wrtieFileTo.close()

    print(f"Done write_chunk_async file: {fileName}")
```

Comment: I don't think `asyncio` does what you want. I think you want `multithreading`?

Comment: What does `write_chunk_async` look like?

Comment: @dano I just added `wrie_chunk_async`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asyncio` only provides concurrency if you are using its APIs to do asynchronous I/O. In your sample code, all of your I/O (reading/writing files) is done using synchronous, blocking APIs, so using `asyncio` doesn't add any value. Now, `asyncio` actually doesn't provide any APIs for asynchronous reading/writing of files, because it is not well-supported at the Operating System level. See [this explanation](https://github.com/python/asyncio/wiki/ThirdParty#filesystem) from the Python wiki.

There is a third-party library, [`aiofiles`](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles), which provides an `asyncio`-friendly API for file I/O, but it's just delegating all the work to background threads under the covers, so there's really no reason to use it you're not trying to integrate file I/O into an application already using `asyncio`. If all your application does is read/write files, just use threads directly. Keep in mind though, that if all your threads are reading/writing files to the same disk, multithreading may not help much, either, since ultimately all threads will contend with each other trying to access the single disk.